# petfinder api is giving a forbidden response when creating app

Tags: python, flask, petfinder

has anyone tried to get a key from petfinder API? everytime I try to create an account for my app it gives me a forbidden code

I was expecting to be redirected to a key, they say its free.

I put my http:///localhost as a url for my app since its still in development stage, a name, and a password

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.